# I can't seem to use IFs within a lazy evaluation

Tags: perl

I've written a very simple script to delete symlinks in a directory, then create new ones linking to files in another directory (files modified within 10 days).

The script worked pretty good, but I thought I'd start showing some output, more specifically only when a $debug (or $quiet) argument is given. This has been giving me some grief, and I don't understand why I'm struggling with this seemingly easy task.

I'm thinking it is because the 'if($debug)' is used within the short circuit of the find sub.  Without any conditional logic, it works fine (as seen in the 2nd find func).

Any thoughts at all will be very much appreciated, thanks.

ERROR:

```
syntax error at symlinksUpdater.pl line 25, 
near "if" syntax error at symlinksUpdater.pl line 26, near "}"
Execution of symlinksUpdater.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Getopt::Long; 
use File::Find;
use Cwd;

my $symDir = getcwd();
my $archiveDir;
my $clearDynamic = 1;
my $debug= '';
my $dryRun ='';
GetOptions ("dynamicDir|s=s" => \$symDir,
            "archiveDir|a=s" => \$archiveDir,
            "clear|c!" => \$clearDynamic,
            "debug|d!" => \$debug,
            "dryRun!" => \$dryRun
        );

print "DEBUG MODE\n" if $debug;

if ($clearDynamic) {
    find(sub {
            -l &&
            unlink &&
            if($debug) {print "DELETE: $_";}    #LINE 25
        }, "$symDir"); }

find(sub {
        -f &&
        int(-M _) < 10 &&
        symlink($File::Find::name, $symDir."/".$_) &&
        print "$symDir/$_ -> $File::Find::name";
        #(printf("\n%s/%s  ->  %s", $symDir, $_, $File::Find::name) if (defined $debug);
    }, "$archiveDir");
```

Comment: I recommend you drop all those short-circuit `&&` operators. They have obviously confused you as much as they will anyone else happening upon your code. The `if` construct was designed for this purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the if statement in a do block like this:

```
if ($clearDynamic) {
  find(
    sub {
      -l &&
      unlink &&
      do { if($debug) {print "DELETE: $_";} }    #LINE 25
    }, "$symDir"
  );
}
```

A prefix if block with curly braces can't stand alone as a statement the way other constructs can. You could also use a postfix if like this:

```
... unlink && (print "DELETE: $_" if $debug)
```

The parentheses clarify that the print should only happen if `$debug` is true rather than that the entire string of `&&` conditions is contingent on `$debug`.

[perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) explains "Compound Statements" (e.g.: `if {...}`) and "Statement Modifiers" (e.g.: `... if EXPR`). I didn't find anything in that document which explicitly says that a compound statement can't be used as an expression, I just know from experience that it can't.

Comment: Heh, quick answer, and it works perfectly now. Thank you! I'm going to have to research why this works now though.

Comment: It works simply because `do-BLOCK` wraps a block of code and allows it to serve as an expression

Answer (score 3):

The operand of `&&` must be an expression, not a statement. Anyway, all you need is

```
find(sub {
   -l && unlink && $debug && print("DELETE: $_");
}, $symDir);
```

But I find the following far more readable:

```
find(sub {
   if (-l) {
      if (unlink) {
         print("DELETE: $_") if $debug;
      }
   }
}, $symDir);
```

It also allows for easy error handling (`else { warn ... }`).

Comment: `&& $debug && print("DELETE: $_");` ... I feel quite silly now. Thanks for answering!

Comment: (The reason it's hard to read is because it doesn't provide any visual distinction between tests, operations and error handling.)